# none of the commands work in linux terminal

Tags: linux, bash, debian, terminal

All of a sudden I can't execute any command in my debian terminal:

```
pi@rpi ~ $ ls
-bash: ls: command not found
```

or

```
pi@rpi ~ $ sudo omxplayer -r -o hdmi mymovie.mkv
-bash: /usr/bin/sudo: No such file or directory
```

or

```
pi@rpi ~ $ nano text.txt
-bash: nano: command not found
```

Nothing works. A minute before everything was fine, I was watching a movie, didn't run anything else. I can't even reboot it properly as `reboot` fails as well. Hard reset is coming... Any idea?

**UPDATE**: I tried to disconnect the ssh session but couldn't connect again. Had to turn it off and back again. It's OK now but this is not the first time this happened. I would really appreciate some tips.

Comment: Drive failure, can you give us the specs of the hardware you're using?  Sounds like either the drive failed or was disconnected.

Comment: Raspberry PI model B. Specs: http://downloads.element14.com/raspberryPi1.html

Comment: try command dmesg. It might be an I/O failure.

Comment: I already restarted it.

Comment: Since `bash` is clearly running, you could try its internal commands, especially `echo`. First try `echo $PATH` (this should include `/bin`); then `echo *` and `echo /bin/*` (this should include `/bin/ls`); finally `if [ -x /bin/ls ]; then echo ls can run; else echo ls cannot run; fi` (this should tell you that `ls` can run).

Answer (score 6):

This could be caused by clearing your `PATH` variable or a drive failure.
One could try `/bin/ls` instead of just `ls`, if that works do `export PATH="/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin"`, that should help.

As stated in comments you're using Raspberry PI, so probably your SD card just got disconnected, unfortunately reconnecting it won't help.

A permanent solution to such problems would be keeping all stuff necessary to (automatically) mount a SD card in a RAM disk, but personally I don't think it's worth it, cause you can always do a hard reset.

### EDIT

In production devices based on Raspberry PI B+ (the one with micro SD cards) we just glued card in slot, that's also a solution.